# Display One-To-Many in Web Api result

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i have one to many relationships, how can i display result which include both of classes?
result like this:

```
class group{
public string username{get;set;}
public string password{get;set;}
public IEnumerable<user> users {get;set;}
}
class user{
public string firstname{get;set;}
public string last{get;set;}
}
```

result:

```
 Group:
        name : low_users
        permission: full
        users:
             user:
             firstname: Denys
             last: test
             user:
             firstname: John
             last: test2
```

its very easy example. i was trying .Include option, but its only return first class, no more.

Comment: I'm a little confused... you have two classes called user. It's not possible to have two classes with the same name in C#, unless they're in different namespaces.

Comment: i'm sorry, i write this code as example. fixed